# Which race can dual-wield Swords the easiest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to dual-wield swords, and I was wondering which race would have an easier start. Also, I would like to know whether they are better at using light armor or heavy armor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that makes dual-wielding easier (or harder!) is the One-Handed skill (or lack thereof!).

Redguards start with the highest one-handed skill, but this initial advantage isn't anything that other races can't overcome with a little bit of effort.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for orc.  Orc's berserk ability to take half damage and do double damage for 1 minute will let you mow down hard targets before they can get you.